# NextJS integration with backend Woocommerce

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, woocommerce, headless

Im working with integration nextjs with backend woocommerce using graphql .

I wonder about one thing.

Currently Wordpress/Woocommerce is installed at:

```
mywebwoo.com - default wp storefront
mywebwoo.com/wp-admin - admin as backend
mywebwoo.com/graphql - graphql
```

Maybe someone has a solution now:

1. How to replace default storefront with headless NextJS application and keep original access  domain to wp-admin as backend  and graphql.

Because currently i need example move full wp code to subdomain example api.mywebwoo.com but maybe is other solution.

I want this because I want keep original checkout woocommerce  page under the same domain as nextjs.

So finally I try get result:

```
mywebwoo.com/* - nextJS application
mywebwoo.com/wp-admin - admin as backend woocoommerce
mywebwoo.com/graphql - graphql woocommerce
mywebwoo.com/checkout - default page woocommerce
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions here.

1. First:

- create a homepage in NextJS
- deploy app (vercel, netlify, AWS, etc.)
- setup homepage redirect inside .htaccess

2. Second:

- create a homepage in NextJS
- statically export your app (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports)
- replace homepage related source code with exported html, css and js files